# find number of characters in a line shell script

Tags: bash, count, character

how can I count the characters (a-z,0-9,A-Z)  from files from a directory which has others subdirectories .I have tried with grep and wc but it didn't works

Comment: Do you want per file count OR a total count?

Comment: total.I have to create a scipt that counts the total number of characters from a directory that can contain another subdirectories in which can be the files with the characters

Answer (score 1):

Use this egrep:

```
egrep -ro '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' *|tr -d '\n'|wc -m
```

OR this:

```
egrep -ro '[[:alnum:]]+' "$1" |tr -d '\n'|wc -m
```

Comment: nice idea, but you're also counting a lot of newlines. add `tr -d '\n'` before wc

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks, Very good point, I was trying to strip `\n` in grep itself but using `tr` simplifies it.

Comment: but the pathway to the directory is an argument $1.How do I send it?

Comment: @user3022764: Try this: `egrep -ro '[a-zA-Z0-9]+' "$1" |tr -d '\n'|wc -m`

Comment: Note that the character class `[[:alnum:]]` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (in the C locale) and might be easier on the eyes

Comment: so...i have to create an one-liner  in a script thet receives like an argument the pathway of a directory that contains more files and others subdirectoires.The  script must write in /home/student/character03 the number of total chr..And I also have to write in an other file.err all the errors that appear during the execute of the script

Comment: @user3022764: Use it like: `egrep -ro '[[:alnum:]]+' "$1" |tr -d '\n'|wc -m > /home/student/character03` though I believe you should also show some efforts and don't just keep asking for new questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script that when you ll run it given the full path of the main folder ( the folder that contains the sub-directories which contains the text files ) as first argument will print out the total count --->>>

```
## $1 will be the total path

## This variable will be
## a list of all sub-directories
sub_dirs=`ls $1`

## Total holding count variable
count=0

## Looping over the
## each sub-directory
for i in $sub_dirs;
do
    ## Looping over
    ## each file
    for j in `ls $1/$i`;
    do
        ## Counting the characters
        total_characters=`wc -c "$1/$i/$j" | awk ' { print $1 } '`;

        ## Adding the result to the count
        count=`expr $count + $total_characters`;
    done
done

## Printing out the total count
echo $count
```

I hope this helps...as i didnt fully understand the question...

Cheers from Greece Stay UNIX!

Comment: i need an onliner with pipes and > i think

Comment: i have to create an onliner in a script like I said before. it receives like argument the pathway to a directory that contains ohers directories and files.and i Have to redirect the total number of chars  from the words that are in those files in a /home/student/chars .But only 0-9 and a-z ,A-Z,without space ot other special chars. In the and, in file.err the script should write the errors that appers during the execution of the script.It is a homework at OS and i has just begun shell scripting.please help.Tomorrow I have an exam

Comment: Ohh now i see...i will try this when i ll be on my city i ll soon travel their i am to an other city where my college is.

Just a question you want the files to remain the same after the count?

Comment: yes.because the system will generate the files and the directories.It is a homework and I have all the inputs.SO my onliner starst like this: find $1 -type f/grep........ and the system will also generate some errors for me to redirect them in a file called .home/student/chars03.err